# jQuery ui modal opened with button click is not loading the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement to display a web page on a modal dialogue. This popup should come up only after button click, where the button has the url path. I have come up with the following code, but it is displaying a blank modal window. Can you please suggest what i might be missing here. Thank you.

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  <meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() { 
    $('#clickMe').click(function(event) {
        var link = this;

    $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function ()
            {

                    $(this).load($(link).attr("href"));

        },         
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'This is popup window',
            show: 'puff',
        hide: 'puff'
        });
    });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
      <button id="clickMe" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, the blank modal opens only on click of Google button. When i click on Yahoo button, no modal is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#clickMe').click(function(event) {
      var link = this;

      $('<div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
          console.log('link', link);
          console.log('link.href should be undefined', link.href);
          console.log('$(link).attr("href") should get you the value', $(link).attr("href"));

          $(this).load($(link).attr("href"));

        },
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        title: 'This is popup window'
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="clickMe" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</button>
<button id="clickMe2" href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</button>
```

**Issue 1:** You have the same `id` on both buttons, `id` has to be unique in whole HTML document.

**Issue 2:** you need to access the `href`'s value using `$(link).attr("href")` (see the attached snippet).

However in this case (demo with Google, Yahoo) you will get CORS (Cross-origin request error). If in your real application you load pages from same domain, that should work.

Comment: Thank you, corrected that. but on Clicking Google, not sure why i am getting a blank window. Can you please help me with it.

Comment: Hi, any help on this please. I am still stuck on this

Comment: That code is OK, you will face only the Cross-Origin issue

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there anyways I can resolve the Cross-Origin issue please?